# How do I escape a % symbol in Swift String

Tags: swift, string, escaping

I know I could just urlEncode this but how would I accomplish this:

```
let strReturn = String(strToConvert.characters.map {
            $0 == " " ? "%20" : $0
        })
```

when I do this I get "Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'String' and 'Character'"

same if I add "%%20"

Comment: Before you go too deep in this direction, what is it that you want to accomplish? Escape a string to make it a valid URL?

Comment: yeah, its more a exercise for myself than anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK if you are only doing this for an exercise. For production code, the best methods to escape a URL string are in the `URLComponents` struct.

Now onto your question... the problem is the return type of your closure: `"%20"` is a `String`, `$0` is a `Character`. Swift does not know how to infer the type.

Change it to this:

```
let strReturn = strToConvert.characters.map {
    $0 == " " ? "%20" : String($0)
}.joined(separator: "")
```

Comment: Ah, thanks, I got myself close, didn't get to the joined part. Just to be clear, will joined(separator: "") always produce a string?

Comment: Yes, here's [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688227-joined)

Comment: passing an empty string as the separator is redundant. Just use `.joined()`